# Currency and Language switcher not showing in Magento iphone theme

Tags: iphone, magento

I can't make Magento showing either the currency nor the language selector in the in-built Magento iphone theme (I'm using Magento CE 1.7). 
Apparently it seems that either the function `"$this->getCurrencies()"` nor the function `"$this->getStores()"` return any value.
The strange thing is that, in my installation, both the currency and the language switcher are working properly with the desktop theme.

Has anyone experienced the same issue with the in-built mobile theme? Any hint?

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same problem yesterday with Magento 1.7.0.2. You can add language selector into the menu in three steps.

I presume you've copied the iphone design package into your package. It's always the best practice to not modify the core files and designs.

**Step 1**
You have to add language block into the header block. Add the following line into the file just after the "checkout.links" block (at the line 70)
*frontend/[YOUR_PACKAGE]/iphone/layout/page.xml*

```
<block type="page/switch" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="page/switch/languages.phtml"/>
```

**Step 2**
You have to add the render command into corresponding HTML template. Add the following line into the `<dd class="menu-box">` block (at the line 38)
*frontend/[YOUR_PACKAGE]/iphone/template/page/html/header.phtml*

```
<dd class="menu-box">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks') ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('checkoutLinks') ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('accountLinks') ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('store_language') ?>   <!-- Add the language block here -->
</dd>
```

**Step 3**
There is some strange thing in the original iphone version of the language HTML template. You have to replace HTML block `<li id="language-switcher">` by `<ul id="language-switcher">`. Edit the language template
*frontend/[YOUR_PACKAGE]/iphone/template/page/switch/languages.phtml*
to be like the following:

```
<?php if(count($this->getStores())>1): ?>
    <ul id="language-switcher">
        <a href="#"><?php echo $this->__('Language') ?>: <span id="current-language"></span></a>
        <ol class="switcher-options" style="display:none;">
            <?php foreach ($this->getStores() as $_lang): ?>
            <?php $_selected = ($_lang->getId() == $this->getCurrentStoreId()) ? ' class="selected"' : '' ?>
            <li<?php echo $_selected ?>>
                <a href="<?php echo $_lang->getCurrentUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_lang->getName()) ?></a>
            </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ol>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Having more than one language specified you should see the language switcher at the end of the slide menu now.
For other blocks like "stores" you can let yourself be inspired by the base/default design pack just like I did it to complete this task :).

Answer (score 0):

Hi i follow all the examples you given but there is nothing currency and language selector showing in the homepage.